# Implementing Multiple Return Types in BISON Semantic Rules

Tags: c++, inheritance, bison

I'm building an AST in BISON, and have created classes to handle building the tree.  I've utilized some inherited classes to store different information (an AddExprNode stores an op (i.e "+"), LiteralNode stores a literal "1.49", etc.)  These inherit from the superclass ASTNode.

I've been provided a grammar file for the language that I'm building my parser for (Micro.)  I run into an issue when I could receive either a literal, variable, or full expression as the return type for a primary.

```
primary           : _OPAREN expr _CPAREN  {
                                          $<node>$ = $2;
                                      };
                | id  {
                          $<var_node>$ = new VarRefNode($1, ASTNodeType::VAR_REF);
                      };
                | _INTLITERAL {
                                  $<lit_node>$ = new LiteralNode(LiteralType::isINT, $1, ASTNodeType::LITERAL);
                                  //$$->printNode();
                              }; 
                | _FLOATLITERAL {
                                  $<lit_node>$ = new LiteralNode(LiteralType::isFLOAT, $1, ASTNodeType::LITERAL);
                                };
```

Here's my union declaration, and the type definitions:

```
%type <s> id str var_type any_type
%type <node> expr_prefix factor factor_prefix postfix_expr expr primary expr_list expr_list_tail call_expr
%type <add_node> addop 
%type <mul_node> mulop 
%type <var_node> primary
%type <lit_node> primary

%type <s_table> decl  var_decl param_decl_tail param_decl_list   
%type <s_entry> string_decl param_decl
%type <str_list> id_list id_tail
%type <st_list> func_declarations if_stmt stmt stmt_list func_body func_decl else_part loop_stmt while_stmt

%union{
  SymbolTableEntry * s_entry;
  char * s;
  SymbolTable * s_table;
  std::vector<SymbolTable *> * st_list;
  std::vector<char *> * str_list;
  ASTNode * node;
  AddExprNode * add_node;
  MulExprNode * mul_node;
  VarRefNode * var_node;
  LiteralNode * lit_node;
}
```

As can be seen above, BISON does not allow you to make the return type ($$) for a single rule (like primary) different based on what tokens you encounter in the rule.

Is there a way to accomplish this?  My google-fu and ability to read the BISON manual seem to be failing me.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> ASTNode * node;
> AddExprNode * add_node;
> MulExprNode * mul_node;
> VarRefNode * var_node;
> LiteralNode * lit_node;
> ```

A variable of type `ASTNode *` can store a pointer to an instance of any subclass of `ASTNode`. So you can get rid of all the `foo_node` definitions above, just keep the `ASTNode * node;` definition and store all of your nodes in that one.

That way the type of your `primary` rule can just be `node` and there's no problem.

Comment: Thanks a million!  This was actually my original strategy, but at first sight it seemed that the parent-class methods were being called as opposed to the child-class method I was targeting.  Your answer gave me the direction I needed.